# Avoiding memory leaks using malloc() in the Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: memory-leaks, malloc, codeblocks

I use Code::Blocks to write my code in C. As far as I know, it combines a text editor, compiler and debugger.

My concern is whether using the `malloc` command without using the `free` function will lead to memory leaks or whether Code::Blocks will clean up by itself after each time I run my program from Code::Blocks?

Comment: Code::Blocks is simply a graphical interface to your compiler/linker/debugger toolchain. It allows you to avoid using the commandline tools yourself by running them for you. It knows nothing about what goes on in your program and has no responsibilities for its
behaviour.

Comment: so that means my codes will result in memory leaks?

Comment: Technically yes, unless you `free` whatever you have `malloc`-ed.
However, leaking heap blocks at end-of-program only, although sloppy,
is harmless, since the OS will immediately reclaim all the memory
your program was using (static, stack and heap). What must be avoided
is leaking heap blocks iteratively within a program loop or recursion,
so that the program runs out of memory before it finishes and fails, or is is killed by the OS. If you make *iterative* calls to `malloc` without
matching `free`s, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, CodeBlocks is just an IDE, which means you can edit, compile, debug and run your codes by using it. However, the software itself(I mean CodeBlocks) cannot disturb or do any impact on the program you write in RUNTIME.

After you "build and run" your code, the operation system will give your program resource (memory and CPU, etc), but OS cannot "rewrite" your program, either.
To avoid memory leak, you should remember to `free` memory after you call the allocator(`calloc` or `malloc`) and use the memory.

To learn more about the tips of memory usage in C, you can read the chapter 9, **virtual memory** of [CSAPP](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/pieces/csapptalk.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Codeblocks is an integrated development environment, but it is not a C++ runtime.  It only integrates with the compiler, and has no control over the execution of your code.

Whenever you call `malloc` you must call `free`.   The platform executing your code will reclaim the leaked memory after your program terminates, but this is not the responsibility of either Codeblocks, or the operating system.

Never call `malloc` without calling `free`.